# SQL - Select Values From A Table Where A Corresponding Value Matches The Results Of Another Select Statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite, select

Since the title is quite confusing, allow me to clarify. In this instance, I am trying to select all *parentemails* of year 10 students. However, the year grade of the students are stored in another table, making the select statement rather tricky.

This is my attempt so far, I hope it highlights the roadblock I am at.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Makes tables
c.execute(
    """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student (
        year INTEGER,
        code INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY (code)
    )
""")

c.execute(
    """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS studentcontact (
        contactcode INTEGER,
        studentcode INTEGER,
        parentemail TEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY (contactcode),
        FOREIGN KEY (studentcode) REFERENCES student(code)
    )
""")

c.execute("""
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO student (code, year) VALUES 
        (501, 9), 
        (502, 10), 
        (503, 10)
""")

c.execute("""
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO studentcontact (contactcode, studentcode, parentemail) VALUES
        (401, 501, "bobjones@email.com"),
        (402, 502, "billwilliams@email.com"),
        (403, 503, "sallydavidson@email.com")
""")

### -- QUERY HERE -- ##

# My attempt so far
query = """
    SELECT code FROM student WHERE year ='10'
    SELECT parentemail FROM studentcontact WHERE studentcode = *results from select statement above*
    """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
SELECT parentemail
FROM studentcontact
WHERE studentcode IN (
    SELECT code
    FROM student
    WHERE year='10'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want `join`:

```
SELECT sc.parentemail
FROM student s JOIN
     studentcontact sc 
     ON s.code = sc.studentcode 
WHERE s.year = 10
```